# VBA if statement function multiply data from two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Vba and I  have been trying to figure out how after an if statement to multiply two numbers in two different columns. the data in excel is laid out as below.What I am trying to do is to multiply the cost with the weight if the freighttype is for example store transfer but my code below does not work.Your help would be much appreciated.I do not know if I need two extra for loops for the cost and weight.

```
    freighttype                
    Column(b)                  

    Store Transfer                      
    Ecommerce   


    Cost        
    Column(c)
    7
    6

    Weight
    column (e)
    2
    3
```

And the code is:

```
    Option Explicit

    Function essay(ft As Range) As Long

    Dim x As Variant

    For Each x In ft
        If ft = "store transfer" Then
            essay = Range("b2:b365").Offset(0, 1) * Range("b2:b365").Offset(0, 3)
        Else
            essay = 0
        End If
    Next x
    End Function
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "Does not work"? What is your expected output, and what is it you get instead? (also: why not just use a formula for this?)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion by not work I mean it does not multiply the cost with the weight when the  freighttype is store transfer the output i get is just 0.I know i can use an if  formula for this but I am trying to learn how to use vba

Comment: You can step through the code with `F8`, and follow it line by line. That may help pinpoint where/why the code isn't returning what you expect.

Comment: I see the data in the cell is "Store Transfer", but the VBA code uses "store transfer". VBA is case sensitive when comparing strings

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Excel, you cannot multiply two arrays together in VBA.

For the equivalent, you can either loop through all the cells, multiplying them one by one and keeping a running total, or you can use the `SUMPRODUCT` worksheet function inside `EVALUATE`

Assuming, for example, that your `ft` range is in column B, starting with B2, you could use something like:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Function essay(ft As Range) As Long
  essay = Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT((" & ft.Address & "=""store transfer"")*OFFSET(" & ft.Address & ",0,1)*OFFSET(" & ft.Address & ",0,3))")
End Function
```

for looping:

```
Function essay2(ft As Range) As Long
    Dim c As Range
    Dim L As Long

For Each c In ft
    If c = "store transfer" Then _
        L = L + c.Offset(0, 1) * c.Offset(0, 3)
Next c

    essay2 = L

End Function
```

Note that the `Option Compare Text` statement makes the routine case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi Guys I managed to solve the problem with your help ,please find the solution below. 


    Option Explicit

    Function ecco(ft As Range) As Long
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim L As Long



    For Each x In ft
    If ft = "st" Then
    L = x.Offset(0, 1) * x.Offset(0, 3)

    Else
    ecco = 0
    End If

    ecco = L

    Next x

    End Function
```